# Use multiple mysql joins

Tags: mysql, join

**Database Scheme**:
http://pastebin.com/aPXk1rMf

I'm want to select "post owner's **uName**" and "comment owner's **uName**" from "comments" table (i.e. I think I need cOwnerID>uName and pID>uID>uName) so that I can log some activities right after a comment is posted.
I tried to use MySQL joins in order to achieve that but I couldn't; so here's what I tried in vain.

```
$result = dbquery("INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('','$pID','$ownerID','$cmnt')"); // inserting a comment

$lastID = mysql_insert_id();

$res = dbquery("SELECT
                users.username AS username
            FROM `comments`
            LEFT JOIN `users` on comments.cOwnerID = users.uID
            WHERE (cID='$lastID')");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use aliases for table users, because, actually, you will have two joins on this table : one for the post author and another for the comment's author.

Try something like this :

```
            SELECT
                commentAuthor.username AS commentauthor_username,
                postAuthor.username AS postauthor_username
            FROM `comments`
            LEFT JOIN `users` AS commentAuthor on comments.cOwnerID = commentAuthor.uID
            LEFT JOIN `posts` on posts.pId = comments.pID
            LEFT JOIN `users` AS postAuthor on posts.uID = postAuthor.uID
            WHERE (cID='$lastID')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT users1.username, users2.username FROM Posts p
WHERE p.pID="$POST_OF_INTEREST"
LEFT JOIN users users1 ON users1.uID=p.uID
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON comments.pID=p.pID
LEFT OUTER JOIN users users2 ON users2.uID=comments.cOwnerID
```

Given a particular post ID, this will get the username of the person who posted and the username of each person who commented on that post (one row per comment).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Users.uName  AS UserNamePost
             , UserComment.uName AS UserNameComment
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Posts
    ON Posts.uID = Users.uID;
INNER JOIN Comments
    ON Comments.pID  = Posts.pID ;
INNER JOIN Users AS UserComment
    ON Comments.cOwnerID   = UserComment.uID  ;
```

This will aim to have the user that has posted the post and then join the user for all comments for the post

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT
    users.username AS username,
    comments.cOwnerID AS commentOwner,
    users.uID AS userID
FROM
    comments
    LEFT JOIN
        users
    ON
        commentOwner = userID
WHERE
    commentOwner = '{$lastID}'";